# Show part of front page on another page

Tags: themes, content

I'm using the Zerif Pro theme on my wordpress website: http://themeisle.com/demo/?theme=Zerif%20Pro%20K

I've added content to the frontpage by customising the theme. I'm trying to show a part of the frontpage on another page.

I have "Packages" on the frontpage, and I'm trying to show this on my "Prices" page as well. I've tried different things, but I can only get it to show nothing or more or less the whole front page. How can I include only this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must separate the template file who you want 
Like

```
get_template_part('file_without_php');
```